# Angular - Recreate Component On Self Route Change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have an angular app with a navigation bar. I have received a request to refresh the components data when the user re-clicks on the link which matches the current page. After a little reading, I understood that I need to set the onSameUrlNavigation to 'reload' and catch the event in the component and refresh the data within it. Although I'm aware this is the best solution and there is no need for the component to be recreated, I am trying to find some quick fix for all my routes without writing a lot of code to support this behavior. Is there a way I can force all my components to be destroyed and recreate when the new route matches the current route? maybe create some kind of directive on router-outlet or some other quick fix?

Best,
Tal Humy

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered a problem where a navigation from `/user/1/roles` to `/user/2/roles` was re-using the component associated with `/roles`. This is because by default, Angular prefers to re-use components where it can, in order to be more memory-efficient.

Start by creating a **CUSTOM ROUTE REUSE STRAGETY** as follows:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

export class DefaultRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
  }
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle|null {
    return null;
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false; // <-- Here is the critical line of code which forces re-creation of the component
  }
}
```

And register it in your **AppModule** as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: DefaultRouteReuseStrategy,
    },
  ],
})
AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have an angular app with a navigation bar. I have received a request
>   to refresh the components data when the user re-clicks on the link
>   which matches the current page.

How is **navigation bar** constructed? Is it an array of `li a` elements with `[routerLink]` binding? If so, you can change that to `(click)=refreshOrGoToPage(path, $event)` binding and do necessary stuff inside event handler.

**Example**

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  refreshOrGoToPage(path: string, event: MouseEvent) {
    if(this._router.url === path) {
      this.refreshData();
      return;
    }

    this.router.navigate([path, {}]);
  }
```

--Edit

[This is open issue in Angular and there some workarounds](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115)

Here's interesting one

> If you navigate manually to the route, you can always navigate to an
>   empty route first, then navigate to the route you want.

You could change example code above with:

```js
if(this._router.url === path) {
  const emptyPath = '/reload';

  this.router.navigate([emptyPath, {}]).then(_ => {
    this.router.navigate([path, {}])
  })
  return;
}
```

Comment: Jozef thank you for the reply, but it seems that using the solution, I still need to implement a refresh data for each component that is bound to a route inside the navbar. I am looking on a smart way to just destroy it and create it again

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Josef again thank you very much for the reply. I thought about doing so, but I hoped that there is a more elegant solution. I might eventually use this approach. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the events of the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Event) class as such:

```
protected previousUrl: string = '';
protected currentUrl: string = '';
```

In the constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) { }
```

In your ngOnInit (or somewhere else):

```
this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
            this.currentUrl = event.url;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not quite sure how to use your approach in order to recreate the component